# how to change the “return to shop” button text?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, buttons

how to change the “return to shop” button text?

i can not find way to change it on woocommerce.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you browse the source code of the plugin, you'll see "*return to shop*" is  used three times in:

```
includes/class-we-checkout.php:956
includes/class-wc-ajax.php:257
templates/car/cart-empty.php:33
```

for the first two, the classes - there's no hooks or filters to change that text. There's no function that conjurors that text either. It is, as it is. However, you can do a work-around and change it with jQuery on your site. In your theme, or a custom plugin, you can add:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', function(){
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
        if (jQuery('a.button.wc-backward'))
            jQuery('a.button.wc-backward').text("My Custom Text");
    });
    </script>
    <?php
});
```

As for the third instance, the template - it too will work with the above, but you can hard code this one if you want. In the file itself, it says:

> This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/cart-empty.php

So you can do that, and hard code the text as desired.